# Upload multipart form from android to vert.x

Tags: android, vert.x

I am trying to upload image with other parameter from Android to Vertx HttpServer. I want to store the parameters into MySQL database and write the image to file.
The problem i got is that only the image bytes of the first request can be fully received by server. the image bytes of the following request can only be received by server partially. So i only part of the image can be uploaded to server. Can anyone help me please? Thanks!
the code in android is like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(params[0]).buildUpon();
            for (String name : LoginMap.keySet()) {
                builder.appendQueryParameter(name, LoginMap.get(name).toString());
            }

            String url = builder.build().toString();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            Log.i("filename", fileName);
            ContentBody mimePart = new ByteArrayBody(fileBytes, fileName);

            mpEntity.addPart("userfile", mimePart);

            httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);

            String result = "";
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                    inputStream.close();
                    Log.i("test",result);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            return result;

        }
```

the code on the server side is:

```
else if (req.path().startsWith("/upload")) {
    req.expectMultiPart(true);

    // can put the pic name in url

    JsonArray fields = new JsonArray();
    JsonArray values = new JsonArray();   
    String[] pairs = req.query().split("&");    
    String[] each;

    for (String pair : pairs) {    
        each = pair.split("=");    
        fields.addString(each[0]);      
        // if(each[0].equals("pic_uri")){    
        // String[] pic = each[1].replace("%2F", 
        // "/").split("/");
        // values.addString(pic[pic.length-1]);    
        // }    
        // else     
        values.addString(each[1].replace("+", " ").replace("%20", " ").replace("%2F", "/"));
    }

    eb.send("io.vertx~mod-mysql-postgresql",    
    getInsertQuery("records", fields, values),    
    new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {  
        @Override    
        public void handle(Message<JsonObject> message) {
            System.out.println(message.body().toString());// debugging   
            if (message.body().getString("status").equals("ok")) {
                    req.response().putHeader( "content-type", "text/plain");
                    req.response().end(STATUS_OK);
                    req.response().close();
           } else {    
                    req.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
                    req.response().end("ERROR");
                    req.response().close();

          }
        }    
    });

    final Buffer body = new Buffer(0);
    System.out.println("ADDR : " + req.remoteAddress());
    req.dataHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {    
        public void handle(Buffer buffer) {   
            System.out.println("I received " + buffer.length() + " bytes");    
            System.out.println("DATA");
            body.appendBuffer(buffer);    
        }   
    });

    req.uploadHandler(new Handler<HttpServerFileUpload>() {
        public void handle(HttpServerFileUpload upload) {   
            String name = upload.filename();    
            upload.streamToFileSystem("uploads/" + name);
            System.out.println("uploads/" + name); 
        }    
    });

  }
```